# API call issue in magento 2.2.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, api

we are working on api call module in magento 2.2.0 where main functionality is using API fetch data from other site and  show data in grid.
we created module for upper version (magento 2.3 and higher) where we use httpgetactioninterface and httppostactioninterface but as this class not existed in magento 2.2 version. we remove those classes and after that we facing two main error

1. Uncaught TypeError: Argument 6 passed to Pulseem\CustomersGroups\Model\Group::__construct()
2. Pulseem\CustomersGroups\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Grid\Collection does not exist

code for collection.php

```
<?php


namespace Pulseem\CustomersGroups\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Grid;


use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Pulseem\CustomersGroups\Model\Group;
use Pulseem\CustomersGroups\Model\ResourceModel\Group as ResourceModel;
use Pulseem\CustomersGroups\Helper\Constants;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = Constants::GROUP_ID;
    protected $_eventPrefix = Constants::TABLE_GROUP_TITLE;
    protected $_eventObject = 'group_collection';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(Group::class, ResourceModel::class);
    }
}
```

we tried many solutions but get same error which i mentioned above.
if you have any solution please provide. thank you in advance.

**edit 1**
if you just suggest replacement or something that we can use in place of  this httpgetactioninterface and httppostactioninterface .

**edit 2**
group.php

```
<?php


namespace Pulseem\CustomersGroups\Model\ResourceModel;


use Zend_Db_Select;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Pulseem\CustomersGroups\Helper\Constants;
use Pulseem\CustomersGroups\Logger\Logger as Logger;
use Pulseem\CustomersGroups\Model\ResourceModel\Group\CollectionFactory;

class Group extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    protected $_date;

    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $_groupCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param DateTime $date
     * @param Logger $logger
     * @param CollectionFactory $groupCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        DateTime $date,
        Logger $logger,
        CollectionFactory $groupCollectionFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_date = $date;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_groupCollectionFactory = $groupCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(Constants::TABLE_GROUP_TITLE, Constants::GROUP_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Process group data before saving
     *
     * @param AbstractModel $object
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _beforeSave(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        $evenType = $object->getEventType();
        $this->_logger->info('before save event type', [$evenType]);

        if (!$object->isObjectNew() && !is_null($evenType)) {
            $this->_cleanEventInGroups($evenType, $object->getId());
        }

        if ($object->isObjectNew() && !$object->hasCreationTime()) {
            $object->setCreationTime($this->_date->gmtDate());
        }

        $object->setUpdateTime($this->_date->gmtDate());

        return parent::_beforeSave($object);
    }

    /**
     * Clean other groups events to prevent 2 groups have save events types
     *
     * @param string $eventType
     * @param integer $newEventGroupId
     */
    protected function _cleanEventInGroups(string $eventType, int $newEventGroupId)
    {
        $groups = $this->_groupCollectionFactory->create();
        if ($groups->getData()) {
            $this->_logger->info('clean events get data', [$groups->getData()]);
            foreach ($groups as $group) {
                if ($group->getEventType() === $eventType && (int) $group->getId() !== $newEventGroupId) {
                    $group->setEventType(Constants::NO_EVENT);
                    $group->setIsActive(Constants::STATUS_DISABLED);
                    $group->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load an object using 'event_type' field if there's no field specified and value is not numeric
     *
     * @param AbstractModel $object
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param string $field
     * @return $this
     */
    public function load(AbstractModel $object, $value, $field = null)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($value) && is_null($field)) {
            $field = Constants::EVENT_TYPE;
        }

        return parent::load($object, $value, $field);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve load select with filter by event_type
     *
     * @param string $event_type
     * @param null $isActive
     * @return Select
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _getLoadByEventTypeSelect($event_type = null, $isActive = null)
    {
        $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
            ['cg' => $this->getMainTable()]
        )->where(
            'cg.event_type = ?',
            $event_type
        );

        if (!is_null($isActive)) {
            $select->where('cg.is_active = ?', $isActive);
        }

        return $select;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve load select with filter by pulseem id
     *
     * @param integer $pulseem_id
     * @return Select
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _getLoadByPulseemIdSelect(int $pulseem_id)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
            ['cg' => $this->getMainTable()]
        )->where(
            'cg.pulseem_id = ?',
            $pulseem_id
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check if group event type exists
     * return pulseem id if group exists
     *
     * @param string $eventType
     * @return int
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function checkEventType(string $eventType)
    {
        $select = $this->_getLoadByEventTypeSelect($eventType, Constants::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->columns('cg.pulseem_id')->limit(1);

        return $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($select);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $pulseemId
     * @return bool
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function getIdByPulseemId(int $pulseemId)
    {
        $select = $this->_getLoadByPulseemIdSelect($pulseemId);
        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->columns('cg.group_id')->limit(1);
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($select);
    }

    /**
     * Check if pulseem group id exists
     * return event type if group exists
     *
     * @param integer $pulseemId
     * @return string
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function checkPulseemId($pulseemId)
    {
        $select = $this->_getLoadByPulseemIdSelect($pulseemId);
        $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->columns('cg.event_type')->limit(1);

        return $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($select);
    }
}
```

Comment: Above mentioned two interface nothing to do with the error. Can you put your Model class code in the question?

Comment: hey thanks for reply , im very new and not have more idea and as i can see code we not define any model class or such thing so can you more specify about code block so i can share the code you want to check.
sorry and thanks @PradiptaSarkar

Comment: You must have Group class under the Model folder. Just share that Group class.

Comment: @PradiptaSarkar i add edit 2 where i add group.php code it has group class. thanks for help.